# My code is throwing an error [Fatal error: Main] can you tell me why?

Tags: android

I'm creating all the objects after onCreate and setContentView but I'm still getting the error [Fatal Error: Main] and it makes my app crash. I've seen people face the same problem but it's when they make objects for their EditText above the setContentView tag and I've tried moving it around but it's just not working for me hope you can help me.  I'll provide you guys with the code... Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //ASSIGNING
        final EditText name=(findViewById(R.id.editText));
        final EditText date=(findViewById(R.id.editText3));
        EditText month=(findViewById(R.id.editText4));
        final EditText year=(findViewById(R.id.editText5));
        Button b=(findViewById(R.id.button));

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //NAME NUMBER
        String s= name.getText().toString();
        char[] n=s.toCharArray();
        int i,total=0;
```

The Error I'm getting:-

```
2019-02-09 13:24:08.085 6934-6934/com.example.numerologysolutions E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.numerologysolutions, PID: 6934
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.numerologysolutions/com.example.numerologysolutions.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:627)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
    at com.example.numerologysolutions.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:81)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Please post the logcat error so we can see why the code is breaking and correctly point you towards a solution

Comment: Updated the query with error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the problem according to your error stack trace. You're trying to **convert a string to a number**.
`Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`